# Facebook share button og:image

Tags: jquery, facebook, share, facebook-social-plugins

I working on **CMS**, which I can't manage to mess around with default meta values

I've added **addthis** share buttons.
then I've used **jquery** to change meta values as following

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('meta[property="og:title"]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$title?>">');
$('meta[property="og:image"]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$image?>">');
});
```

when clicking on **facebook share button**, **title** is changed as needed but **image** is not changed.

how can I make it work on image value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the page loads just once, I can assign the OG:IMAGE URL once... But I really would like to have each picture with its own OG:IMAGE, since this is a photo album.

Changing OG meta tags client-side is of no actual use – because Facebook will read those tags through it’s scraper, which means they will do an HTTP request for your URL and see what’s in the HTML code; and the scraper does not execute any JavaScript.

Solution: Provide an individual URL for each photo with its own meta information – and have your like button/share functionality/whatever FB feature point to that URL for each photo.

(How you handle things *client-side* does not matter – you can still display all the photos in one page, load new content via AJAX, whatever you like – but you *will* need separate URLs for your photos for them to be recognized as individual Open Graph objects.)

Comment: Thanx, but how it come that "title" is changed and "image" is not affected ?

Comment: Actually the moment your url loads og:Image loaded in dom that's why.